MSI installs when used in command line but not when it's clicked
I have a MSI installer for my WPF application. Usually it's built and deployed via an AzureDevops pipeline but it fails since 8th of April. I think it's important to note: there were no code changes done that could impact the installer.
Once I click on the installer (and provide it with admin privileges once it asked) and try to get the application installed - it fails:

That's what I've grabbed from the Windows events:

There are some log I've grabbed from the app update which is also failed:
MSI (s) (44:74) [04:16:25:443]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 59164 (0xE71C).
MSI (s) (44:60) [04:16:25:949]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (44:60) [04:16:25:952]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
Action start 4:16:25: LoadConfig.
SFXCA: Failed to create temp directory. Error code 5
CustomAction LoadConfig returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 4:16:26: LoadConfig. Return value 3.
Action ended 4:16:26: INSTALL. Return value 3.

However if I run the installer via command line - it works! I used this command:
msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt

P.S. It happens with installers built by the AzureDevops pipeline. If I build it locally - it works as usual.
Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen and how to get it working again? Thanks in advance!

This looks like a clue - SFXCA: Failed to create temp directory. Error code 5 - see https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/8078

stuartd yes, seems to be so

Do NOT downgrade your WiX version. You will be vulnerable to known security issues. Instead, upgrade you Custom Action project to use the v5 nupkg. It should be a drop-in replacement and has no known security vulnerabilities.

The problem was about the changes done in the WiX: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/8078.
While waiting for the fix we did a workaround by downgrading the version in the pipeline:
choco install wixtoolset --version 3.14 --allow-downgrade --force -y


This is terrible advice. You will be vulnerable to known security issues. Do NOT do this.

Thanks for your reply. This is really just a workaround to get production up and running as quickly as possible. But by this point we've updated the Custom Action project to use nupkg v5 and it works.
